Restart Windows 11 remotely when rdesktop completely fails (cannot send input)
Is there any way to force Windows to reboot itself remotely when rdesktop fails completely? I can't get it to accept any form of key combination or at a minimum, it is unresponsive to ctrl+shift+end/del/win+b/etc. I'm using a Microsoft account so psexec is a no go.
rdesktop accepts my credentials and begins logging on, but then ends with the standard "Your Remote Desktop Session has ended..."

Not to be overly sassy, but Bing is lying to you. Feel free to give it a shot. The authentication mechanisms aren't the same between psexec and a microsoft account. PSExec hits LSA whereas microsoft accounts don't. See OP for comments on ctrl+alt+del, like I said, it's a no go

There are other remote control products than RDP.

@harrymc I may be misunderstanding. I got it figured out, but is there something on that list that allows a user to remotely reboot a remote device that is currently being problematic? I obviously didn't have the ability to install anything on a host I didn't have access to.

See Reboot Windows 10 PC remotely.

It seems something breaks during the login itself. Microsoft's rdesktop client uses Network Level Authentication (NLA) and pre-auths your creds before connecting to the session, but Linux's rdesktop does not.
On a hunch that something was happening with NLA/during the login sequence, I connected via rdesktop on Linux and it dropped me to the login screen. Interestingly, attempting to login still failed however, I was able to simply reboot the host with the power button on the login screen.
TLDR: Try rdesktop from Linux and see if it gets you the login splash screen and then reboot.
